# Makefile syntax: what is $(RM)?

Tags: c, bash, macos, unix, makefile

I saw the following Makefile online ([here](http://qiita.com/j8takagi/items/74232a00cc33623f7844)):

```
hello:

clean:
    $(RM) hello
```

When there is a hello.c file in the same directory with the Makefile, `make` command in Terminal builds `hello` executable. When `make clean` is run, `hello` executable is removed by `rm -f hello` instead. So, `$(RM) hello` means `rm -f hello` here.

- What does $(FOO) mean? Is it a special syntax of Makefile, or something bash command?
- Can I run other commands as well as $(RM), like $(PWD)?

Comment: $() is variable expansion in make.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a Makefile variable. There are explicit variables (which are defined inside a Makefile) and implicit variables (defined by make, can be overriden by you).

You can see a list of implicit variables with this flag:

```
make -p
```

some of the most common variables can be found at: [10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)

You can expand a variable with the syntax `$(NAME)` or `${NAME}`

Answer (score 10):

`$(RM)` is a reference to a "make" variable (or *macro* in POSIX lingo). These come in two syntax flavors, with identical semantics: `$(NAME)` and `${NAME}` (and there are one letter macros not needing parentheses, such as `$a`).

[POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) many variables, errrrr, *macros*, to have a default:

```
MAKE=make
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=-rv
YACC=yacc
YFLAGS=
LEX=lex
LFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=
CC=c99
CFLAGS=-O 1
FC=fort77
FFLAGS=-O 1
GET=get
GFLAGS=
SCCSFLAGS=
SCCSGETFLAGS=-s
```

Interestingly, `RM` isn't one of them.
The default value for the `RM` variable in your make implementation apparently is `rm -f` (and your make runs in non-POSIX mode by default).

Note that while `$(PWD)` has the same syntax as a shell command substitution (and `${PWD}` the same as a shell parameter), they are completely different things. To answer your question, no, you can't expect `$(PWD)` as a "make" macro to run the `pwd` utility or expand to the current working directory. An undefined macro will be expanded to an empty string without "make" even raising an eyebrow.

Comment: Thanks Jens for answering! What is non-POSIX mode? Is my make run in some other mode because it's run on macOS, which I use?

Comment: @Keita No "make" I know of runs in POSIX mode by default. There are always a ton of non-POSIX features available. For POSIX mode, POSIX says that you need a special target named `.POSIX:` near the top of your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

It's a make file [variable](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html). Previously or in your env you have `RM="rm -f"` syntax depending on the shell or if it's in the make itself, and now you're just executing.

You can run `pwd`, but to use `$(PWD)`, you need to set `PWD="pwd"`.